# Confusion about the execution order in SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-algebra

I'm studying databases with the book "Database System Concepts" from Silberschatz, Korth and Surdashan (I quote the authors because the relational algebra notation is different against other authors...

Well, I think that the execution order of a SQL query  it's based in the relational algebra, for example:

If I have this SQL query:

```
SELECT nombre_sucursal, AVG(saldo) AS media_sucursal
FROM cuenta
GROUP BY nombre_sucursal
HAVING media_sucursal > 800
```

The corresponding relational algebra expression is the following:

```
Π nombre_sucursal (σ saldo > 800 (nombre_sucursal Ģ avg(saldo) (cuenta))
```

Well... For that, in my opinion, the execution order in a SQL query is (if you look at the relational algebra expression backwards):

1. **FROM** - *(cuenta) the base relation in the relational algebra expression*
2. **GROUP BY nombre_sucursal** - *nombre_sucursal Ģ avg(saldo) in the relational algebra expression*
3. **HAVING media_sucursal > 800** - *σ saldo > 800 the selection operation in the relational algebra expression*
4. **SELECT nombre_sucursal, AVG(saldo) AS media_sucursal** - *Π nombre_sucursal **???***

I put the ??? symbols because this is the part that I don't understand:

**If the SELECT clause is the last part of a SQL query, how can I rename the result of the aggregation function as "media_sucursal" and in the HAVING clause I'm able to use it?**

I checked this [**question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2617661/whats-the-execute-order-of-the-different-parts-of-a-sql-select-statement) but it confirms what I put above, but not answer my question.

Any help is welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it is the behavior of MySql extension to `GROUP BY`

> **[MySQL Extensions to GROUP
>   BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-extensions.html)**
>   MySQL extends this behavior **to permit the use of an alias in the
>   HAVING clause for the aggregated column**

You can disable that extension with `sql_mode` [`ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by)

```sql
SET [SESSION | GLOBAL] sql_mode = ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY;
```

If you try to execute above-mentioned query in `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` sql_mode you'll get as the following error message:

> Non-grouping field 'media_sucursal' is used in HAVING clause: SELECT
>   nombre_sucursal, AVG(saldo) AS media_sucursal FROM cuenta GROUP BY
>   nombre_sucursal HAVING media_sucursal > 800

as expected.

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6fa65/2)** demo that illustrates that.

Comment: Damn! This mean that if I'll change the DBMS in a future (for example SQL Server) I'll have another features and extensions outside the SQL standard?

Comment: Unfortunately yes. There are a lot of things that are vendor specific. But in that particular case you can use an expression with an aggregate function in `HAVING` clause instead of an alias. That will work in all major RDBMSes the same.

Comment: Yeah, it is a bit irritating that mysql has this on by default to coax users into complacency when coming from other DBMS.