# ROW_NUMBER and multiple JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server

When I test this request:

```
SELECT 
    *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY test1) AS lineNumb 
FROM 
    (SELECT DISTINCT 
        tab1.test1, tab2.test2
     FROM TB_tab1 tab1
     JOIN TB_tab2 tab2 ON tab2.test3 = tab1.test3 
     JOIN TB_tab3 tab3 ON tab3.test4 = tab1.test4 
     WHERE tab3.test5 != 'test') AS sub
WHERE lineNumb BETWEEN 1 AND 5
```

I get:

> Error: column name invalid : 'lineNumb'. SQLState: S0001 ErrorCode: 207

Why and how can I correct my request?

Comment: This [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1466963/sql-row-number-function-in-where-clause) should help you rewrite the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why:

You cannot access the aliased lineNumb column in the where clause of your select--it isn't defined in the context.

How to correct:

Use what you have as a subquery or CTE and select from that using your where.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM (<you existing query without the where>)
 WHERE lineNumb <= 5
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM 
(
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY test1) AS lineNumb FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT tab1.test1, tab2.test2
FROM TB_tab1 tab1
JOIN TB_tab2 tab2 ON tab2.test3 = tab1.test3 
JOIN TB_tab3 tab3 ON tab3.test4 = tab1.test4 WHERE tab3.test5 !='test') as sub
) as sub2 
WHERE lineNumb BETWEEN 1 AND 5
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use a column alias in a `where` at the same level.  You can do what you want with analytic functions.  You don't even need the `distinct`:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT tab1.test1, tab2.test2,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY tab1.test1, tab2.test2 ORDER BY test1) as seqnum,
             DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY test1) as lineNumb
      FROM TB_tab1 tab1
      JOIN TB_tab2 tab2 ON tab2.test3 = tab1.test3 
      JOIN TB_tab3 tab3 ON tab3.test4 = tab1.test4
      WHERE tab3.test5 <> 'test'
     ) sub
WHERE lineNumb BETWEEN 1 AND 5 AND seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out the order of execution in a SELECT statement in this question:

[What's the execute order of the different parts of a SQL select statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2617661/whats-the-execute-order-of-the-different-parts-of-a-sql-select-statement)

The SELECT clause isn't read until late in the execution of the statement. So, you can't reference the alias until you get to the ORDER BY clause.