# INNER JOIN clause ignoring NULL values

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, join

I am looking to query some data that pertains to medications a patient has been prescribed that are in a certain category. But I also want to show patients that do not have any medications. My query so far:

```
    SELECT
    pd.fname,
    pd.lname,
    pp.drug_name,
    pp.drug_strength
FROM
    patient_data pd 
     FULL OUTER JOIN patient_prescr pp on pp.pid = pd.pid 
     FULL OUTER JOIN formulary f on pp.med_id = f.id 
     INNER JOIN formulary_categories fc on f.category = fc.id AND fc.id in (34,36,37,38,5)
WHERE
    pd.lname = 'Test'
```

When applying the `INNER JOIN` to `formulary_categories`, I can correctly specify the category in which the drug I want to specify, but when I do this, it WILL NOT include patients that do not have any medications.

With the `INNER JOIN` joining the formulary_categories table, my results look like this:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
fname       | lname          | drug_name                | drug_strength
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
Cathy         Test             Clonazepam                 0.5mg
Larry         Test             Librium                    25mg
Jennifer      Test             Vistrail                   25mg
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

If I change the `INNER JOIN` to a `FULL OUTER JOIN`, it simply ignores the `category` constraint, and pulls all categories.

However, the query will not include patients that do not have any medications prescribed. Id like my results to look something like:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
fname       | lname          | drug_name                | drug_strength
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
Cathy         Test             Clonazepam                 0.5mg
Larry         Test             Librium                    25mg
Joe           Test             NULL                       NULL
Jennifer      Test             Vistrail                   25mg
Steve         Test             NULL                       NULL
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Try `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are actually looking for LEFT JOIN:

```
SELECT
    pd.fname,
    pd.lname,
    pp.drug_name,
    pp.drug_strength
FROM
    patient_data pd 
     FULL OUTER JOIN patient_prescr pp on pp.pid = pd.pid 
     FULL OUTER JOIN formulary f on pp.med_id = f.id 
     LEFT JOIN formulary_categories fc on f.category = fc.id 
         AND fc.id in (34,36,37,38,5)
WHERE
    pd.lname = 'Test'
```

A `LEFT JOIN` will not filter data if a correlation is not found between the values in the two tables (or result sets) and will display a `NULL` value for the columns which displays data from the table where a correlation was not found (just like in your expected output sample).

You can also take a look at the best article (in my opinion) for understanding all types of JOINs, [**here**](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins).

Comment: Thanks for the answer Radu. How do you handle `categories` that are `NULL`? I tried to apply: 

`LEFT JOIN formulary_categories fc on f.category = fc.id 
         AND fc.id in (34,36,37,38,5) and fc.id IS NOT NULL`, but the results still contain drugs with NULL values.

Comment: @etm124 If you want to filter the NULL values in this scenario you need to add your `fc.id IS NOT NULL` condition at the end, in the `WHERE` clause, like: `WHERE pd.lname = 'Test' AND fc.id IS NOT NULL`. Doing the `IS NOT NULL` check in the JOIN section you're directly looking in the table `fc.id` column if it is `NULL`, not in the displayed results. But I assume you have no `NULL` values in your `ID` column, hence no values are being filtered. Maybe you could also take a look at [**how a query is executed**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2617679/1266737) and practice with LEFT and INNER joins

Answer (score 1):

You simply need `LEFT OUTER JOIN`  :

```
  SELECT
    pd.fname,
    pd.lname,
    pp.drug_name,
    pp.drug_strength
FROM
    patient_data pd 
     FULL OUTER JOIN patient_prescr pp on pp.pid = pd.pid 
     FULL OUTER JOIN formulary f on pp.med_id = f.id 
     LEFT OUTER JOIN formulary_categories fc on f.category = fc.id AND fc.id in (34,36,37,38,5)
WHERE
    pd.lname = 'Test'
```