# SELECT SomeColumn where SUM(SomeOtherColumn) of any N rows or less is a certain value

Tags: mysql

I got totally stumped by this skill assessment question. The skill assessment is done. I am too old to use SO to cheat my way through... Just curious how to solve this.

You have a table with the following columns:

```
Sender | Recipient | Date | Amount
```

How would you select all Recipients that each have a sum of ANY 3 or fewer amounts that is greater than or equal to X?

For example:

```
Sender  | Recipient |    Date    | Amount
--------+-----------+------------+-------
William | Jane      | 2016-05-27 |  $1243
Sarah   | Josh      | 2016-05-12 |   $500
Rohit   | Tammy     | 2016-05-24 |   $200
Jacob   | Josh      | 2016-05-17 |   $500
Abraham | Josh      | 2016-05-15 |    $10
Marie   | Vivian    | 2016-05-16 |  $1243    
Alex    | Josh      | 2016-05-07 |   $150
```

If X = $1024, you should get Jane, Vivian and Josh. Josh, because $500 + $500 + $150 > $1024.

**SOLUTION**
All the three solutions worked. Thanks so much guys. Really appreciate it.

Chose @Tim Biegeleisen's answer for the simplicity factor.

Comment: What version of SQL are you using?

Comment: What about Vivian? What is the Rdbms?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2617661/whats-the-execute-order-of-the-different-parts-of-a-sql-select-statement look at the clauses of a sql query, there is a specific one for yor need

Comment: That's right Vivian too. This is MySQL.

Comment: Yes, this will be a pain in mysql. It doesnt support limits in correlated subqueries.

Comment: it could also be vivian josh and tammy. Your question is vague.

Comment: @drew I dont think the order of the names matter that much. but it could be based off of highest to lowest on single amounts

Comment: It is just not defined what the output must be. As described, I could find what I said. I could also find a row that merely outputs Vivian. Also Vivian and Josh. etc

Comment: Obviously, you wouldn't store the '$'

Comment: Please let us know if there might be duplicates and if so how can one record be distinguished from another.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One trick which will work is to generate a row number for each `Amount`, for each `recipient`.  Then we can simply restrict to the greatest three amounts for each group using a simple `WHERE` condition.

```
SELECT Recipient, SUM(Amount)
FROM test t
WHERE (SELECT 1 + COUNT(*)
     FROM test
     WHERE Amount >= t.Amount AND Recipient = t.Recipient AND
           date < t.date) <= 3
GROUP BY Recipient
HAVING SUM(Amount) >= 1024
```

This solution uses the transaction date to break ties (e.g. in the case of Josh receiving $500 in two different records).  This solution is not robust to the use case of a recipient having two transactions for the same amount on the same day.  One nice thing about this solution is that it does not require the use of any user defined variables.

## SQLFiddle

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't work. It gives me Jane and Vivian only. Tried to create a SQL fiddle but it hangs.

Comment: Yes, that's the challenge :( ... but at least it gives me a close enough solution.

Comment: @KalC I updated my answer to use the transaction date to break a tie, and it works, at least for the sample data you showed us.  Really, if you expect to have two records which are completely identical then you should consider at least adding an id column of some sort.

Comment: This solution worked. This is a bad table design. This was part of a skill assessment process.

Comment: Assessment: Many SO users have a lot of database skill (especially [this guy](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1144035/gordon-linoff)).

Answer (score 2):

You could use variables to number records per receiver in order of descending amount, and then filter for those records that have received a number not more than 3:

```
select   receiver,
         sum(amount)
from    (select   @num := if(@rec = receiver, @num + 1, 1) as rn,
                  @rec := receiver as receiver,
                  amount
         from     transaction
         order by receiver,
                  amount desc) as numbered
where    rn <= 3
group by receiver
having   sum(amount) >= 1024
```

[SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3bfcd9/1)

The nice thing about this solution is that it uses variables to avoid the base table being queried twice, which on large data sets can have a huge performance impact.

Also, it guarantees that at most 3 records will be returned per receiver, even if in the third place there would be a tie: you'll never get 4.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is grab the top 3 of every recipient. and if their sum is greater than the set limit then you can return their names

```
SET @x = 1024;
SELECT t.Recipient
FROM (
    SELECT 
      Sender, 
      Recipient, 
      Amount, 
      SUM(Amount) as total_amount,
      @count := if(@rec = Recipient, @count + 1, 1) as counter,
      @rec := Recipient
  FROM test
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT @count := 1, @rec := '') t
  GROUP BY Recipient
  HAVING counter <= 3
  ORDER BY Recipient, Amount desc
) t
WHERE t.total_amount >= @x;
```

**[FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0ed7a/1)**

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thanks a lot. This is very elegant. Lot to learn from.

Answer (score -2):

```
;
WITH cte
AS (SELECT
  t.amount,
  t.recipient,
  1 AS cnt
FROM transfers t
UNION ALL
SELECT
  t1.amount + t2.amount,
  t2.recipient,
  cnt + 1
FROM cte t2
INNER JOIN transfers t1
  ON t1.recipient = t2.recipient
  AND t1.amount + t2.amount <= 1024
WHERE cnt <= 2)
SELECT
  *
FROM cte
WHERE amount >= 1024
```