# Is there any specific order of execution in SQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

I am confused about the execution order of SQL queries.

For example, (`Inner join` in `MySQL` in the code below), between `WHERE` clause and `SELECT * FROM` clause, which one gets to be interpreted and executed first?

That is to say, does the query below bring `*`(all) of the `tables data` first then find the cases that match with `WHERE` condition? or Do they just find the list of `data` that match with `WHERE` condition and then `SELECT * FROM` from the `WHERE` result?

```
SELECT * FROM customers, orders
WHERE customers.id = orders.customer_id;
```

As above case, I am wondering how the SQL queries are executed in general.

Comment: https://www.periscopedata.com/blog/sql-query-order-of-operations

Comment: The whole point of languages like SQL is for you to describe (logically) *what you want*, and to leave it up to the optimizer about *how best to produce that result*. That's why e.g. execution order is far more loosely defined with SQL than with many procedural languages.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the execute order of the different parts of a SQL select statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2617661/whats-the-execute-order-of-the-different-parts-of-a-sql-select-statement)

Comment: See [ask]. Please research.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a *logical* order to evaluation of the query text, but the database engine can choose what order execute the query components based upon what is most optimal. The logical text parsing ordering is listed below. That is, for example, why you can't use an alias from `SELECT` clause in a `WHERE` clause. As far as the query parsing process is concerned, the alias doesn't exist yet.

1. FROM
2. ON
3. OUTER
4. WHERE
5. GROUP BY
6. CUBE | ROLLUP (these are not present in MySQL but are in some other SQL dialects)
7. HAVING
8. OVER (window functions)
9. SELECT
10. DISTINCT
11. ORDER BY
12. LIMIT (or, in MSSQL, TOP)

See [the Microsoft documentation (see "Logical Processing Order of the SELECT statement")](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#logical-processing-order-of-the-select-statement) for more information on this.