# Using a SELECT subquery with alias and FROM together

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to do a count and a from on an aliased subquery, but can't figure out how to add the filtering portion:

```
SELECT  webpages.*, (select count(*) 
                     from webpage_opportunities 
                     where webpage_opportunities.webpage_id = webpages.id) as test_count 
FROM "webpages" 
WHERE (webpages.clicks IS NOT NULL) AND "webpages"."website_id" = 144 AND test_count = 0
GROUP BY webpages.id ORDER BY "webpages"."clicks" DESC LIMIT 50 OFFSET 0
```

The `test_count` column shows up in the query results when I remove the `AND test_count = 0` but once I add it, the query fails. I also need to make sure the subquery connects to the webpages table, as stated in thje join above.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Referring to a Column Alias in a WHERE Clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8370114/referring-to-a-column-alias-in-a-where-clause)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  w.*, COUNT(wo.id) -- but will be 0 because the HAVING
FROM webpages w
LEFT JOIN webpage_opportunities wo
  ON w.id = wo.webpage_id
WHERE (w.clicks IS NOT NULL) 
  AND w."website_id" = 144
GROUP BY w.id 
HAVING COUNT(wo.id) = 0
ORDER BY w."clicks" DESC 
       , COUNT(wo.id) -- optional
LIMIT 50 OFFSET 0
```

Comment: There was a minor typo but this might do it! 

`
SELECT  w.*, (select count(*) 
                     from webpage_opportunities 
                     where webpage_opportunities.webpage_id = w.id) as test_count
FROM webpages w
LEFT JOIN webpage_opportunities wo
  ON w.id = wo.webpage_id
WHERE (w.clicks IS NOT NULL) 
  AND w."website_id" = 144
GROUP BY w.id 
HAVING COUNT(wo.id) = 0
ORDER BY w."clicks" DESC 
LIMIT 50 OFFSET 0
`

Comment: I didnt think you need it because you filter by `test_count = 0`?

Comment: I add the `COUNT()` to the select

Comment: We might do something like `HAVING COUNT(wo.id) > 5` then we want to display and sort by the test count.

Comment: I'm not sure what was the typo? But you don't need a sub query to calculate the `COUNT`

Comment: Thanks, this is definitely progress. Can I also sort by the count as well? ORDER BY total_count DESC

Comment: Great! Is there any way to alias the COUNT(wo.id) throughout so it doesn't have to get repeated throughout?

Comment: Did you see the duplicate question link? Or check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2617661/whats-the-execute-order-of-the-different-parts-of-a-sql-select-statement)  to understand the order how SQL process the query. As you can see, the `SELECT` is on the last steps, so you don't have an alias until then. If you have an alias you can use it on the `ORDER BY` but not before